# Why do i get linebreaks?

Tags: c++

How can i make it in the same line?

It looks like:

```
You see a closed door.
It belongs to house 'Magician's Alley 
5a'. 
Nobody owns this house.
```

But I want it to look like:

```
You see a closed door. It belongs to house 'Magician's Alley 5a'. Nobody owns this house.
```

the code:

```
void House::updateDoorDescription()
{
std::stringstream houseDescription;
houseDescription << "It belongs to house '" << houseName << "'. " << std::endl;

if(houseOwner != 0){
    houseDescription << houseOwnerName;
}
else{
    houseDescription << "Nobody";
}
houseDescription << " owns this house." << std::endl;

HouseDoorList::iterator it;
for(it = doorList.begin(); it != doorList.end(); ++it){
    (*it)->setSpecialDescription(houseDescription.str());
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are doing

```
<< std::endl
```

This is `endline` and puts a linebreak. Remove these and it will be what you want to have.